Why is my mesh showing these splits when changing pose?

As you can see in the image, when I move the mesh, it shows these splits. The rig is made with rigify. I'm quite a newbie to Blender rigging.

It looks as if the mesh is made from lots of seperate disconnected parts or objects. We'd need to see your Blend file to find out what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's smaller than 30Meg following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Switch your mesh to Edit mode, select all and try a M > Merge by Distance, if it doesn't work please share your file

@moonboots this solved the problem. It still doesn't look very realistic, but it doesn't have to be. Thanks!

Switch your mesh to Edit mode, select all and press M > Merge by Distance.
